# 12-bit pipelined adder

Tags: digital-logic, vlsi, adder, computer-arithmetic

I have been given the task of designing a 12-bit pipelined adder:

[image]

There are 4-bit adders connected by latches.
**Why are latches used between the 4-bit adders? Is it for synchronization?**

Comment: I haven't designed it yet, this is a project , we are supposed to use flip flops but I am unable to understand its need, also could you be a nicer i am new to this field. Thanks

Comment: @jonk Comments should be respectful, please read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/conduct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adder will have different inputs at each clock cycle. The output will appear two clock cycles later. You need all paths from input to output to have the same (cycle) delay so the outputs & intermediate results correspond.

It might help to draw a line through the corresponding latches to separate the 'time zones' as such.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is for synchronizing the carry from one 4 bit adder to the next.

The adder at the bottom performs addition of the lowest significant bits. The higher input bits are held in latches until the carry is ready for them at the next clock cycle.

The sum out of the lower bits is held until the sum of the higher bits are ready.

This technique is used if the adder word is too large (too wide) to complete an addition in one clock cycle.

Comment: i want to know what happens if the flip flop is removed?

Comment: Based on what I wrote, what do you think happens? Do you understand the role of a carry?

Comment: Why cannot i directly give that as input to other adder is what i am asking

Comment: It's a matter of WHEN  to give that as input to other adder. Do you understand the role of a carry?

Comment: yes, so that the corresponding carry gets transferred for the cycle that has the corresponding sum bits, now i get it.